# Session hanging with TM REQUEST and plan handle 0x0000

Tags: sql-server

We have a periodic event where lots of connections hang on TM REQUEST (from `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`) and make no progress. `KILL` on the affected `session_id` does nothing

The server runs database mirroring (2008R2). Pausing and resuming mirroring fixes the issue when it happens.

The session stuck in this state are unkill'able. The load on the mirror is the usual, not bursty. Once a high number of connections are stuck in this state, the system freezes up and the mirror stops replicating (all queries get blocked).

Anyone seen this before and know what is causing it? There is nothing in the error logs.

Comment: What mode is mirroring configured as ? What are the wait types when this issue occurs ? Any chance that SQL Server is configured in `fiber mode`?

Comment: Mirroring is in Sync mode. No fibers. No other waits

Comment: What was the `resource_description` set to?

Comment: I noticed this too not too long ago(we run async, but we change it to sync when we do failover, or patching etc). Does the spid stay after the DBs are fully synchronized?

Comment: The SPID disappear after the pause. But they are unkillable while the problem is going on

Comment: Is the mirror choking on the load? is it STND or ENT Edition. (1 vs multiple redo threads). Can you relate the incidents to preceding bursts of hi transactional load? For example does it  happen after/during maintenance?

Comment: @EdwardDortland: Enterprise Edition. The load is normal when it happen, nothing out of the ordinary for the mirror. But once a certain amount of queries get stuck in this state, all requests to the database get blocked.

Answer (score 10):

TM stands for Transaction Manager. The current command being set to TM
Request means that the thread is currently servicing a DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) request, either to enlist in a DTC transaction, or defect from it, or commit it, or so on. Distributed Transactions are not supported for Database Mirroring because it can't guarantee transaction integrity.  Suppress your DTC transactions and this should go away.

Comment: Credit S. Ashwin, colleague, Microsoft SQL Support

Comment: How would I diagnose where this is coming from? The MSDTC logs on the server are empty

Comment: Could the DTC get involved if I has a cross database transaction on the same instance?

Comment: @ThomasKejser - is `sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'` on? - Perhaps some system is issuing cross-database transactions using `OPENQUERY` ad-hoc statements or something?

Comment: @MaxVernon: No, we have that option turned off

Comment: Cross database transactions use the same fundamental code as DTC transactions use.   The main difference is the lack of the DTC manager of coordination.  Instead SQL Server elects the lowest DBID in the transaction to be the transaction coordinator.

Comment: Dumb question, if my DBA says "No DTC on this server", would there still be a reason I see "TM REQUEST" command entries in sysprocesses?

Answer (score 0):

Service Broker uses the SQL Servers transaction manager instead of Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC). The transaction is not across instances but within an instance. Are you using Service Broker?